# MySQL - Too many joins! Only display records if user has permission

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a MySQL query for a small project management CMS I'm developing with PHP. I have four tables; projects, projectInfo, projectUsers & accounts. I can use JOINs to get a list of all projects for all users, along with their most recent project name and description. However, I would like to see all projects that a specific user is contributing on (from table projectUsers). Each project has a creatorId in the projects table, which I can query by adding " AND a.creatorId = 1" to the end of the query below. However, I also need another query that will display all the same project information if the users' foreign key exists in projectUsers table.

Query to display all projects with relevant information:

```
SELECT p.projectId, p.projectInfoId, p.userId, a.creatorId, p.updatedTimestamp, p.projectName, a.timestamp, a.projectType, accounts.firstname, accounts.lastname 
FROM projects AS a 
JOIN projectInfo AS p ON p.projectInfoId = ( SELECT pi.projectInfoId FROM projectInfo AS pi WHERE pi.projectId = a.id ORDER BY pi.updatedTimestamp DESC LIMIT 1 ) 
INNER JOIN accounts ON a.creatorId=accounts.id 
WHERE a.deleted = 0
```

Gives me the following results:

```
| projectId | userId | creatorId | updateTimestamp     | projectName              | timestamp           | projectType | firstname | lastname |
| --------- | ------ | --------- | ------------------- | ------------------------ | ------------------- | ----------- | --------- | ---------|
| 155       | 1      | 1         | 2022-07-25 10:10:28 | Chicken Nugget Dispenser | 2022-07-25 10:04:01 | Production  | Ryan      | Admin    |
| 156       | 1      | 1         | 2022-07-25 10:05:44 | Nugget Juice Dispenser   | 2022-07-25 10:05:44 | Design      | Ryan      | Admin    |
```

projects table

```
| id       | timestamp           | projectType | creatorId | deleted |
| -------- | ------------------- | ----------- | --------- | ------- |
| 155      | 2022-07-25 10:04:01 | Production  | 1         | 0       |
| 156      | 2022-07-25 10:05:44 | Design      | 1         | 0       |
```

projectInfo table

```
| projectInfoId | projectId | userId | updatedTimestamp    | projectName              | projectDescription                         |
| ------------- | --------- | ------ | ------------------- | ------------------------ | ------------------------------------------ |
| 172           | 155       | 1      | 2022-07-25 10:10:28 | Chicken Nugget Dispenser | Dispenses chicken nuggets, idk... Update 2 |
| 171           | 155       | 1      | 2022-07-25 10:10:24 | Chicken Nugget Dispenser | Dispenses chicken nuggets, idk... Update 1 |
| 170           | 156       | 1      | 2022-07-25 10:05:44 | Nugget Juice Dispenser   | Dispenses chicken nugget juice.            |
| 169           | 155       | 1      | 2022-07-25 10:04:01 | Chicken Nugget Dispenser | Dispenses chicken nuggets, idk...          |
```

accounts table

```
| id | username | password | email | role    | firstname | lastname |
| -- | -------- | -------- | ----- | ------- | --------- | -------- |
| 1  | admin    | ******** | ***** | Admin   | Ryan      | Admin    |
| 35 | manager  | ******** | ***** | Manager | Ryan      | Manager  |
| 36 | user     | ******** | ***** | User    | Ryan      | User     |
```

projecUsers table

```
| id  | addedTimestamp      | projectId | userId | addedBy | 
| --- | ------------------- | --------  | ------ | ------- |
| 213 | 2022-07-25 10:04:01 | 155       | 35     | 1       | 
| 214 | 2022-07-25 10:04:01 | 155       | 36     | 1       |
```

I have attempted to solve this by adding "INNER JOIN projectUsers ON 1=projectUsers.userId", but I end up with no results. I have also tried subquerying projectUsers, as well as a few attempts at IF EXISTS, to no avail. Eventually, my PHP script would replace the foreign key "1" with the userId from the database, using the $_SESSION variable, so the user can view all projects that they are assigned from the projectUsers table.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Ryan.

Comment: hm i dpn't see ay permissions in yor tables

Comment: The permissions are userId in projectUsers. If a user has been invited to participate in a project, their userId will appear in projectUser, corresponding to the projectId of that project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided permissions are `projectUsers(projectId,UserId)`

```
    SELECT p.projectId, p.projectInfoId, p.userId, a.creatorId, p.updatedTimestamp, p.projectName, a.timestamp, a.projectType, accounts.firstname, accounts.lastname 
    FROM projects AS a 
    JOIN projectInfo AS p ON p.projectInfoId = ( SELECT pi.projectInfoId FROM projectInfo AS pi WHERE pi.projectId = a.id ORDER BY pi.updatedTimestamp DESC LIMIT 1 )
    INNER JOIN projectUsers pu on pu.projectId = a.id
    INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts.Id = pu.UserId 
       and accounts.id = ?
    WHERE a.deleted = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply! I ran the query, replacing the "?" with "35", which is a userId in projectUsers, linked to the Chicken Nugget Dispenser project and Manager user  , but I get no results.

Comment: Misprint is corrected, try it again

Comment: That's got it, thanks! Take my invisible upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You want many rows from 4 tables, there mus be enough joins for that.

you choice for aliases, are very bad, you must see at once which table is the source

> ```
> SELECT
>  pu.`projectId`,pi.`projectInfoId`, pu.`userId`,pr.`creatorId`
>  ,pi.`updatedTimestamp`,
>  pi.`projectName`,pr.`timestamp`, pr.`projectType`
>  ,ac.`firstname`, ac.`lastname`
> FROM
> projecUsers pu 
> JOIN projects pr ON pr.`id` = pu.`projectId`
> JOIN projectInfo pi ON pr.`id` = pi.`projectId`
> JOIN accounts ac ON pr.`creatorId` = ac.`id`
> WHERE pu.`userId` = 35 AND pr.`deleted` = 0
> ```
>
> ```
> projectId | projectInfoId | userId | creatorId | updatedTimestamp    | projectName              | timestamp           | projectType | firstname | lastname
> :-------- | ------------: | :----- | --------: | :------------------ | :----------------------- | :------------------ | :---------- | :-------- | :-------
> 155       |           172 | 35     |         1 | 2022-07-25 10:10:28 | Chicken Nugget Dispenser | 2022-07-25 10:04:01 | Production  | Ryan      | Admin   
> 155       |           171 | 35     |         1 | 2022-07-25 10:10:24 | Chicken Nugget Dispenser | 2022-07-25 10:04:01 | Production  | Ryan      | Admin   
> 155       |           169 | 35     |         1 | 2022-07-25 10:04:01 | Chicken Nugget Dispenser | 2022-07-25 10:04:01 | Production  | Ryan      | Admin
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=787fcc1137fb844f716f0a102ccbb5f8)*